# webpack does not include css file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I have build a react-stepper and uploaded it to github.
When i want to build my App, webpack does not include font-awesome css. But it includes my own style.scss file. I use the style loader in webpack.
In dev mode everything works fine. Only in build mode it does not work.
Here is my repo:

https://github.com/tkwant/react-stepper-wizard

Here is my webpack.build.config file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "react-stepper-wizard.js",
    library: "Stepper",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  externals: ["react", "react-dom", "font-awesome"],
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./examples",
    hot: true,
    port: 9001
  }
};
```

It would be fine if somebody can help me here or can do a PR to fix this problem.

Comment: It should not be in the `externals`. That is for excluding modules from the package.

Comment: when I remove it from externals it doesnt work, too

Answer (score 1):

You're copying a `.css` file, right? 
You may want to try the [webpack-copy-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)

Comment: can you explain how to use it? I dont understand why my scss file is loaded but the css file not. I have imported it in stepper.js the same way

Comment: The `README.md` file covers the use of it fairly extensively. You just load it in the Webpack plugins and follow the config for the files that you want to copy

Comment: ok i will try it. But it is still a bit confusing why the scss file is loaded and the css not...

Answer (score 0):

solution was to use url loader.

```
 { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
  { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
```